# EditText not working when a TextView is refreshing with a timer value

Tags: java, android, timer

I have a timer, which is refreshing a TextView with the current timer value. I also have a EditText.
So, when the timer is running, and I want to write something in the EditText, the TextView freezes, and I can't see any text in the EditText while I'm writing. So, I press the back button to hide the keyboard and stop focusing the EditText, and the TextView just get again the normal, and in this moment I can see what I have written inside the EditText.

Here goes the runnable. The EditText is a simple EditText.

```
private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

    public void run() {

        timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

        updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;
        int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
        int mins = secs / 60;
        secs = secs % 60;
        int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
        timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", secs) + ":"
                + String.format("%03d", milliseconds));
        timerValue.setText(mins+":"+secs);
        customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

change the time of the delay, it's set on zero now

```
customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);
```

to something like this:

```
customHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);//every second
```